# Dropdown menu resizing when zooming in&out page in IE8

Tags: html, css, asp.net

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="ctl00_m_adminEngine_pnlGridCriteria" class="formContainer pnlGridCriteria">
  <div class="CriteriaDiv">
   <span id="ctl00_m_adminEngine_lblCriteriarcc_id">Category: </span><select name="ctl00$m$adminEngine$ddlrcc_id" id="ctl00_m_adminEngine_ddlrcc_id" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="0">&lt;ALL&gt;</option>
    <option value="11">Application</option>
    <option value="12">Design</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="500">Maintenance Practices</option>
    <option value="501">Manufacturing</option>
    <option value="502">Normal &amp; Expected</option>
    <option value="503">Undetermined</option>

   </select>
  </div>


</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have some minor problem with dropdown menu. When user is zooming in/out the page, dropdown menu resize itself and stays like that until someone reloads the page. [Here is the video explanation](http://screencast.com/t/Vo0mwy78HM).
I tried setting height attribute with fixed value i.e. 20px, it's then not resizing but text inside is shifting down anyway.
It happens only in IE8.

Comment: You should share your code here, and besides this, your video link is broken. Edit your question in order to someone help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found partial answer for this.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2728884